# Unlink Multiple images using a loop

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a code that is supposed to delete image name from mysql table and the actual image from the server folder. The name deletes from database but the actual images are not deleting. Below is the code:

```
 $sql_queryy = "SELECT imImage FROM gimage WHERE imID = '$chkbxk'";
 $photoresultt = mysqli_query($connBiscup, $sql_queryy);
 //$row_album_images = mysqli_fetch_assoc($photoresultt);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($photoresultt)) { 

        unlink($target . $row[0]);
        unlink($targett . $row[0]);
 }
```

Any help please

this was the initial code.

```
for($i=0; $i<$N;$i++){

            $chkbxk = $_POST['checkbox'][$i];

            $sql_queryy = "SELECT imImage FROM gimage WHERE imID = '$chkbxk'";
            $photoresultt = mysqli_query($connBiscup, $sql_queryy);
            //$row_album_images = mysqli_fetch_all($photoresultt);
            foreach ($row_album_images as $row)
            {
                unlink($target . $row[0]);
                unlink($targett . $row[0]);
            }
}
```

but because of the mysqlnd issue, i changed to a while loop.

Comment: If $target and $targett are correct paths then checout folder's permisions.

Comment: I advise you to echo your paths and make sure they point to right locations.

Comment: And `mysqli_fetch_assoc` fetches associative array btw.

Comment: The folder paths are correct. i had initially used mysqli_fetch_all but there is no mysqlnd installed on the shared host. So i had to change to a while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to `mysqli_fetch_array`

`mysqli_fetch_assoc` will return associative array (i.e. `['imImage'=>'img1']`)

`mysqli_fetch_array` will return both associative and numeric array (i.e. `[0=>'img1','imImage'=>'img1']`).

Otherwise
you may rewrite loop body to use associative array.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($photoresultt)) { 

        unlink($target . $row['imImage']);
        unlink($targett . $row['imImage']);
}
```